# How do I create and call an Action<T> when I only know T at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, delegates

How do I create and call a delegate `Action<T>` when at runtime I'm receiving the delegate as an object and I know type only at runtime?

For example, In Foo, I define my delegate and want to pass it to a method which receives an `Action<int>` as an object, along with the data to pass to the delegate. It's contrived I know, but it's to demonstrate my problem.

```
public void Foo()
{
    Action<int> handler = i => Console.WriteLine(i + 1);
    Process(handler,4)
}

public void Process(object myDelegate, object data)
{

}
```

and I'd like to call

```
myDelegate(data)
```

Comment: Where do you get to know that T is int here?

Comment: Based on what you've shown us so far, both manoijlds and Quinton Bernhardt's answers should work.  If there's a particular reason they don't, please be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the delegate types (Eg. `Action<string>`) Are actually types that have an `Invoke(...)` method.

You should look for that invoke method with reflection and call it, It is relatively slow - So watch out.

This should do it :

```
Action<string> action = s => Console.WriteLine("Hello " + s);
object obj = action;
// Invoking
obj.GetType ().GetMethod ("Invoke").Invoke (obj, new object[] {"World"});
```

This works too, I don't know what is faster, you should check it out :

```
Action<string> action = s => Console.WriteLine("Hello " + s);
Delegate obj = action;
obj.DynamicInvoke(new [] { "World" });
```

Comment: Thanks Shani, the Dynamic invoke works fine, and I can test which is faster

Answer (score 3):

So maybe this then:

```
    public void processAction<T>(Action<T> action, T item) {
        action(item);            
    }

        Action<int> customAction = (i) => Console.WriteLine(i);
        processAction(customAction, 123);

        Action<string> customAction2 = (s) => Console.WriteLine(s);
        processAction(customAction2, "Frank Borland");
```

Comment: Thanks Quinton, I've updated the question to clarify. The object that gets passed into myDelegate is any number of different Action<T>. I guess I need somewhat of creating that typed delegate and then invoking it.

Comment: See above :) I can't use generic method call because type is only know at runtime

Comment: @JasonHyland I believe it should be possible to make the above approach work.  Have you tried it?  As shown in Quinton's example, you don't have to explicitly specify the <T> in your code if it can be inferred from the parameters.

Comment: @Quinton Apologies, my example isn't very clear but I only have object custom and object customAction2 (in your answer above), I can't therefore pass them into processAction<T>

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
Action<int> handler = i => Console.WriteLine(i + 1);
Process(handler, 4);

public void Process(object myDelegate, object data)
{
    ((Delegate)myDelegate).DynamicInvoke(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given a whole lot of context here, but can't you rewrite you `Process` method as:

```
public void Process<T>(Action<T> myDelegate, T data)
{
    myDelegate(data);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, at the time of calling Process, all I have in an object which holds a Action<T> - I can't call Process<T> because I only know the type at runtime